# Datagridview specific rows change background color

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, cells

i try to highlight the selected row become red where column is 'E' in datagridview but if the first row's status is 'E',the following row also become red too although status is 'I'.

[image]

**SelectionChanged event**

```
int sel = datagridview.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
    DataGridViewRow Row = dataGridView.Rows[sel];
    if(!File.Exists(path))
    {
       Row.Cells[4].Value = "E"
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       {
          Row.Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
       }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: can you please give the CellClick or selectedIndex event code of the grid

Comment: Hi, I already edit it showing code is SelectionChanged event and i don't use CellClick or selectedIndex event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the dataGridView_CurrentCellChanged event can solve this problem.